# Can i change a list into string, modify it, and change it to list again?

Tags: python, regex, string, list

for instance, i have a list like this:

```
lista = ['abc', 'alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie']
```

then i change this into string and modify it:

```
lista = str(lista)
re.sub('a','b', lista)
```

then i'll get a 'string' like:

```
lista = ['bbc','blphb','brbvo','chbrlie']
```

i want this to be a list again.

any suggestions? or can i modify things in the list? simple way would be the best.

EDIT:
I'm using beutifulsoup's findall on making the list. the code is like:

```
desclist = soup.findAll('description')
desclist[:] = (x.replace(r'.+', ' ') for x in desclist)
print desclist
```

i'm trying to change '.' or '.'s to a ' '
but it says nonetype object is not callable..

Comment: suggestion: Don't use a hacky method like replacing letters of string representation of list...

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to convert the list to a string. There is also no need to use a regex for a simply string replacement. Simply perform the replacement on every item in the list and storing them in a new list:

```
lista = [x.replace('a', 'b') for x in lista]
```

You could also modify the list in-place:

```
lista[:] = (x.replace('a', 'b') for x in lista)
```

Comment: I timed this and using a generator on the slice assignment is slower than a list comp, do you have any case where it would be faster?

Comment: wow thanks! i didn't know that it could be so simple like this! you helped me a lot :)

Comment: uh oh.. i have a error that says 'nontype object is not callable..'  what should i do :(

Comment: wait i'll add it on the question

Comment: That might not be a regular python `list`. Don't use the in-place syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to act on each member of your list:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: lista = ['abc', 'alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie']

In [3]: lista = [re.sub('a','b',x) for x in lista]

In [4]: lista
Out[4]: ['bbc', 'blphb', 'brbvo', 'chbrlie']
```

Comment: Are you sure? I've changed the answer to show all the steps. (I've changed letter ell which can be confused with number one in case that was a problem.)

Comment: it works on your example, but doensn't work on mine.. :(
    desclist = [re.sub('a','b',x) for x in desclist]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: but are the elements of desclist strings?

Comment: oh.. it isn't..:( i used beautifulsoup so its type isn't string... can i change it? sorry to bug you...